# Symbol for kernel and range of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

I'm wondering what symbol is used for the kernel and the range of a linear transformation. I've seen them being written as such:

$\ker(T)$

$\mathcal{R}(T)$

Are these the "correct" symbols for the kernel and range, or do they differ between different mathematicians? Are there any that are used more frequently? This *is* being a bit pedantic, but I'm just curious.

Comment: I've also seen $\text{im} (T) $ used for range.

Comment: For the former, I've also seen $\mathcal{N}(T)$; for the later, it's right.

Comment: Usually, $\ker T$ is paired with $\operatorname{im} T$, and $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is paired with $\mathcal{N}(T)$.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Feel free to answer your own question with what you have learned! It is highly encouraged on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel Fisher gave a good comment which I'm putting here:

Both of the notations are correct, but usually those two are not used together because of consistency. Here are the "pairs" that are usually used together for the kernel and the range:

$\ker T$ and $\operatorname{im} T$

$\mathcal{N}(T)$ and $\mathcal{R}(T)$